# Bugged script reload in Blender 2.90.1

Tags: scripting

If I hit the "Reload Scripts" command in the most recent blender snap

`latest/stable:     2.90.1 2020-09-23 (47) 187MB classic`

I get this cryptic error message:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    def fn():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

location: <unknown location>:-1

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

This happens regardless of which .blend-file I open up and which Addons are within my load order.

This does not happen on the older

`2.83lts/stable:    2.83.6 2020-09-09 (46) 170MB classic`

---

**UPDATE:**

I managed to reproduce this error also in the (Linux) binary that can be downloaded from Blender's homepage.

Comment: grep your blender folders for `def fn`  .. do you have any scripts in `..../2.90/scripts/startup`  folder?

Comment: The grep returned no finds (except for something within the blender binary, maybe that's our culprit?). Within my ```scripts/startup``` directory there were a bunch of folders with python code, however no matches for ```def fn```.

Comment: How are you executing the operator? From the search <kbd>F3</kbd> or python console?

Comment: @RobertGützkow I am using the F3-menu to execute the operator.

Comment: FYI op  is also available via top LH corner  blender icon menu `Blender > System > Reload Scripts`  Meant to mention too, as well as your install folders there are your user folders, on ubuntu for example  `~/.config/blender/2.90/`    Latest post would suggest that it is an external script.

Comment: @batFINGER my user folders are not the problem since this bug also occurs if I execute Blender as superuser. https://developer.blender.org/T81112 suggests that the devs are already aware of the issue.

Comment: Good one.  Consider putting together an answer, or could close as "about a bug in blender"  NP  kinda meant . ** ("if") it is an external script to look there .  Built 2.91 three days ago. Luckily missed issue. (if it were to come up)  Having issues building as  bpy module first build since last 2.90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is actually a bug in 2.90.1 (see https://developer.blender.org/T81112).

It will probably be fixed once 2.90.2 rolls out.